# Nested Layout Implementation in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, templates, layout, view, zend-framework2

I need to load a layout of my module but not replacing main layout. That means I want to keep Application/layout.phtml and want to load MyModule/layout.phtml and also I want to load my action.phtml from my controller.

All the solution of nested layout point by replacing Application/layout.phtml by new one.

Just one possible solution I found from [Nesting layouts/views keeping the content variable in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664159/nesting-layouts-views-keeping-the-content-variable-in-zend-framework-2) but its need to implement some extra code every time of my controller. Also, its depend on post-dispatch that is extra process load.

Is there any other clean way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by overriding default ViewModel class -

```
namespace MyModule\Extension;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
class MyModuleViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private $innerTemplate;
    private $myLayout = 'my-module/layout/layout';
    public function setTemplate($template) {
        $this->template = $this->myLayout;
        $myTemplate = (string) $template;
        $this->innerTemplate = new ViewModel($this->variables);
        $this->innerTemplate->setTemplate($myTemplate);
        $this->innerTemplate->parent=$this;
        $this->addChild($this->innerTemplate);
        return $this;
    }
    public function setLayout($layout) {
        $this->myLayout = $layout;
        return $this;
    }
    public function setVariable($pName, $pVar){
        if(isset($this->innerTemplate)) $this->innerTemplate->setVariable($pName, $pVar);
        return parent::setVariable($pName, $pVar);
    }
    public function setVariables($variables, $overwrite=NULL){
        if(isset($this->innerTemplate)){
            if(isset($overwrite)) $this->innerTemplate->setVariables($variables, $overwrite);
            else $this->innerTemplate->setVariables($variables);
        }
        if(isset($overwrite)) return parent::setVariables($variables, $overwrite);
        else return parent::setVariables($variables);
    }
}
```

if you put your layout file into "layout" folder under your module's view root, its works fine. if you want a different layout then you need to call setLayout('my-module/layout/mobile.phtml');

now int your controller you need to use this custom view model like the following way -

```
public function indexAction() {
    /* your action code in your controller */
    return new MyModuleViewModel();
}
```

this layout/layout.phtml works as wrapper for your module. the above code will load three different layout. "main layout" > "module specific layout" > "action template"